# How do I update a specific item in a List?

Tags: sharepoint-server, rest, android

I just want to update a specific field in a list. How do i do that. I'm developing
an android application that updates certain values to the list that I have created in Share point. I'm able to insert a row in the list but i'm not able to update a specific row. Below is my android code.

```
public void updateListItems()
{

    try {
        CookieManager cookieManager = (CookieManager)CookieHandler.getDefault();
        cookies = cookieManager.getCookieStore().getCookies();
        String body ="{ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.ClockTrackListItem' },'UId' : '171028', 'CurrentDate' : '2016-08-05T04:00:00Z' ," +
                "'TimeIn' : '10:12:12' , 'TimeOut': '22:12:12' ,'TotalTime': '10:12:12' ,'Title': 'Dharma'}";
       Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://cloudapps.cctspl.com/sites/ClockInClockOut/_api/Web/lists(guid'"+retrieveList()+"')/items");
       // Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://cloudapps.cctspl.com/sites/ClockInClockOut/_api/Web/lists/GetByTitle('ClockTrack')/GetItemById(5)");
        URL url = new URL(uri.toString());
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setDoInput (true);
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("content-type", "application/json;odata=verbose");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("X-RequestDigest",getRequestDigest());
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("X-HTTP-Method-Override","MERGE");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("If-Match","12");

        urlConnection.connect();
        OutputStream os = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
        os.write(body.getBytes());
        os.flush();
        os.close();
        int resCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
        Log.d("Response Code :" ," "+resCode);
        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader reader =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((inputStream)));
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        String line;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            buffer.append(line + "\n");
        }
        String restResult = buffer.toString();
        Log.d("----Buffer String-----:" , restResult);
        JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(restResult).getJSONObject("d");
   }  catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.v("Retrieve List", e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Can anyone guide me with this. tell me where I have committed a mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update the url to contain the item id 
example: `http://site url/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle(‘Test')/items(item id)`

Reference : [Working with lists and list items with REST](http://url:%20http://site%20url/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle(%E2%80%98Test')/items(item%20id))

Comment: Uid is a field in my list. It's not the item Id.

Comment: Ok, please see my updated answer